# Symfony2 Form Datetime bug

Tags: symfony

I have a problem when I try to create a crud in symfony2. I can't show the datetime choice. I always get this problem.

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\MonthChoiceList::__construct()
>   must be an instance of IntlDateFormatter, null given, called in

Any idea?

FormType code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) 
{ 
    $builder 
        ->add('nome') 
        ->add('email') 
        ->add('senha') 
        ->add('is_super') 
        ->add('is_active') 
        ->add('created') ; 
}
```

Comment: Show some formtype code.

Comment: public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        
        $builder
            ->add('nome')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('senha')
            ->add('is_super')
            ->add('is_active')
            ->add('created')
        ;
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by installing the [php_intl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php). the package is php5-intl in Ubuntu.

Comment: I thought it could be a dll extension missing. But it's installed like Symfony documentation is recommended.

Comment: have you verified that it's actually installed correctly by testing with sample code in your controller? Try one of the samples included in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.create.php) for `IntlDateFormatter`. Also, please confirm that your `created` field is defined as a date type.

Comment: and you tested `IntlDateFormatter` as I suggested?

Comment: Wampserver was the problem. Please, install php5.3+ and Appache2.2+ standalone. Don't use these packages(lamp) to run Symfony2 in local server.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot ! You need intl : then deactivate it (with wamp/php 5.3.9) !

> If you use Wamp and PHP 5.3.9, this problem may disappear if you
>   turn off the intl extension.

Sometimes intl extension is missing dlls. You copy your icu*.ddl from your php folder in your apache/bin/. (Probably because in wamp php.ini is in apache/bin).

Comment: It's strange, but disabling Intl extension get rid off error. I’ve used it only on my developer’s machine…